# Compute $P(X > 10)$ and $P(X+Y > 10)$ for $(X,Y)$ i.i.d. geometric random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent geometric random variables, each with expected value $\frac{5}{3}$. Compute
>   $$P(X > 10)\qquad P(X+Y > 10)$$

The solution is :
$$P(X > 10)=\left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^{10}$$
$$P((X+Y)>10)=\left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^{10}+{{10}\choose{1}}\cdot \left( \frac{2}{5} \right) ^{9}\cdot \frac{3}{5}$$

I understand the solution for $P(X>10)$ as all fails till 10th trial including 10th. I do not understand the solution for $P(X+Y>10)$.

Comment: What is the role of $Z$? What's your try?

Comment: Conditioning on the value of $Y$, $$P(X+Y>10)=P(Y>9)+\sum_{n=1}^9P(X>10-n\mid Y=n)P(Y=n)$$ that is,  using independence, $$P(X+Y>10)=P(Y>9)+\sum_{n=1}^9P(X>10-n)P(Y=n)$$ Now, can you identify every term?

Comment: Oh, and there is no (geometric-probability) in here.

Answer (score 0):

**Imperative!:** There are two distributions commonly called Geometric, so it is always *important* to establish *which* is the one you are talking about.

Your solution for $\mathsf P(X>10)$ indicates that $X$ is the count of *trials until a success*.   $X>10$ being the event of the first success occuring on a trail after the tenth; that is of reaching the tenth trial with zero successes.   Thus obtaining:$$\mathsf P(X>10)~=~{(\tfrac 25)}^{10}$$

Then $X+Y$ is the count of *trials until the second success* in an indefinite series of independent and identical Bernoulli trials.

$X+Y>10$ is thus the event of reaching 10 trials with either zero or one success.   If the success occurs it may be any of those 10 trials.

$$\mathsf P(X+Y>10) ~=~ {(\tfrac 25)}^{10} + \tbinom{10}1 {(\tfrac 25)}^{9}(\tfrac 35)$$

Comment: Cannot there be two successes before reaching 10 trials? Say X = 6 and Y = 6, then X+Y > 10

Comment: That has the second success on the twelveth trial.  Remember $X+Y$ counts all the trials you do until stopping.

Comment: okay, I got it. I was confused that both the trials are running parallely. Thanks for the help!